# Enterprise Library 5.0, CreateSprocAccessor and Timeout

Tags: timeout

Is there a way to set the **timeout** for **CreateSprocAccessor(...)** in Enterprise Library 5.0?

Cause the default timeout is not working for long stored procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing:  adding a timeout in the connection string doesn't solve the problem.

I found a workaround: You can modify the source code of EL 5.0 and generate a new custom DLL.

- in ...\EntLib50Src\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\SprocAccessor.cs
- in Execute(...) method
- add this code just before return:    command.CommandTimeout = 120; // 2 mins
- Compile and use the new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll that you can find in ...\EntLib50Src\Blocks\bin\Debug

Answer (score 0):

actually, I think there is no need to have your own copy of EL. In order to keep original EL binaries unchanged, you just can do the follow:

- inherit from SprocAccessor class
- overwrite Execute() method, put here the same code as in SprocAccessor.Execute() but adding the timeout part
- you will need also to keep in local variable (in your new class) procedureName as this variable is private in SprocAccessor class

some thing like this:

```
public class SprocAccessorWithTimeout<T> : SprocAccessor<T>
{
    readonly string procedureName;

    public SprocAccessorWithTimeout(Database database, string procedureName, IRowMapper<T> rowMapper) : base(database, procedureName, rowMapper)
    {
        this.procedureName = procedureName;
    }
      public override IEnumerable<T> Execute(params object[] parameterValues)
      {
            using (var command = Database.GetStoredProcCommand(this. procedureName))
            {
        command.CommandTimeout = MaxSpExecutionTimeout;

                if (parameterValues.Length > 0)
                {
                    Database.AssignParameters(command, parameterValues);
                }

                return base.Execute(command);
            }
        }
    }
```